# mongoose compound index for fixed value field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to make a compound index, where one of the fields have a fixed value?

Let's say I want to avoid users using the same e-mail for different accounts, but just for regular user accounts, and I want to allow admins to use the mail in as many places as they want, and even have a regular user account and an administrative account using the same e-mail

```
User.index({ username: 1, email: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Is not useful, since it will not allow admins to reuse the email. Is it possible to do something like?

```
User.index({ role: "regular_user", username 1, email: 1}, { unique: true });
```

Comment: I posted an answer on indexes, this may help you decide if its good for you to create a compound index, with one of the fields having a fixed value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545339/how-does-the-order-of-compound-indexes-matter-in-mongodb-performance-wise/33546159#answer-33546159

Comment: Good answer. Actually, in my case, I'm improving a schema inheritance wrapper for mongoose (https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend), and I have to change all the unique keys to discriminator/key unique indexes, but only for those values of the discriminator that define such field as unique. The example above is the easiest I could find to explain it.

Comment: How did things work out for you?

Comment: I have an idea based on your answer. I'll let you know (and accept your answer) tomorrow

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it is useful for the question as I asked it, and may be useful to others. I'm still stuck with this, anyways :-p

Comment: I'm glad I could help a little bit. Sorry to hear that :p

Comment: I did it the hackiest way ever, using a discriminator field with a 2dsphere index... I'll show you as soon as I upload the package to npm... I'm resurrecting a dead npm module (no activity in three years), and I didn't choose a good name xD

Comment: looking forward to seeing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luis,

In regards to the example that you gave. If you create a unique compound index, individual keys can have the same values, but the combination of values across the keys that exist in the index entry can only appear once. So if we had a unique index on `{"username" : 1, "role" : 1}`. The following inserts would be legal:

```
> db.users.insert({"username" : "Luis Sieira"})
> db.users.insert({"username" : "Luis Sieira", "role" : "regular"})
> db.users.insert({"username" : "Luis Sieira", "role" : "admin"})
```

If you tried to insert a second copy of any of the above documents, you would cause a duplicate key exception.

**Your Scenarios**

I think that if you added an `allowance` field to your schema. When you do inserts for admins for new accounts. You can add a different value for their admin allowance. If you added unique index for `{"username":1,"email":1, "allowance" : 1}`

You could make the following inserts, legally:

```
>db.users.insert({"username" : "inspired","email": "i@so.com", "allowance": 0})
>db.users.insert({"username" : "inspired","email": "i@so.com", "allowance": 1})
>db.users.insert({"username" : "inspired","email": "i@so.com", "allowance": 2})
>db.users.insert({"username" : "inspired","email": "i@so.com", "allowance": 3})
```

Of course, you'll have to handle certain logic from the client, but this will allow you to use an allowance code of `0` for `regular` accounts and then allow you to save a higher allowance code (incrementing it or adding custom value for it) each time an `admin` creates another account.

I hope this offers some direction with using unique compound indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. First things first, if you define an index with the `role` like this

```
User.index({role: 1, username: 1, email: 1}, { unique: true });
```

Mongo will use `null` for documents that do not specify the `role` field. If you insert an user without specifying the `role` and try to add it again, you will get an error because the three fields already exist in the database. So you can use this to your advantage by not including a role (or you can use a predefined value for better reading, like you proposed as `regular_user`).

Now, the tricky part is forcing the index to permit admins to `bypass` the uniqueness constraint. The best solution would be to generate a some hash and add it to the role. So, if you just add admins with roles like `admin_user`, you won't bypass the constraint. Meanwhile, using a role like `admin_user_635646` (always with varying suffix) will allow you to insert the same admin multiple times.